# How to activate virtual environment in Django for Windows with Python?

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

I've been told that to activate a Virtual Environment in Django for Windows I should try:

```
environment_path\Scripts\activate
```

But when I enter that, cmd returns this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I created the virtual environment by entering:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

However when I try `env\Scripts\activate` I get the error described.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Activating a virtual environment on Windows depends on where you are running it from. From the Windows Command Prompt, the command is:

- `environment_path\Scripts\activate.bat`

If the Git-Bash shell is being used, which adds several useful tools and a more Unix/Linux-like environment, then the command is:

- `source environment_path\Scripts\activate`

I have found the [prerequisites](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/pre-requisite-installations.html#_setting_up_your_virtualenv) section of *Test-Driven Development with Python* aka ["the Testing Goat book"](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) to be handy in getting Django, Python and related things setup on Windows.

Comment: when I try "source environment_path\Scripts\activate" I get the following error: "'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command". From what I've read, "source" does not work with Windows.

Comment: If you are using 'Command Prompt' then you want `environment_path\Scripts\activate.bat` instead.I would recommend getting the Git for Windows binary and following the instructions under the 'Windows Notes' in the Prerequisites section in the TDD book to install the Git-Bash shell which is much nicer than the standard Windows command prompt

Comment: I am using command prompt. `environment_path\Scripts\activate.bat` does not work either.

Comment: How does the `.bat` not work ? I have both Python3.6 and Python3.7 installed and neither provide a `python3` executable. If I run `C:\Python37\python.exe -m venv test_venv`, then `test_venv\Scripts\activate.bat` works fine. Maybe you have an odd version of python and can try reinstalling from www.python.org/downloads ? Or try creating a fresh venv ?

Comment: Well I ran `env\Scripts\activate.bat` and I get the same error, "The system cannot find the path specified." 

I ran `python3 -m venv env` to create the virtual environment in the first place... am I perhaps entering something wrong there which means it's not creating the virtual environment?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I found how to: probably you downloaded from external source like github. Even that the env is there you must enter the full path, like this: F:\projetos2\PROJFINAL\ProjetoFinal>F:\projetos2\PROJFINAL\ProjetoFinal\myenv\Scripts\activate


Adding to that, also in this case you will need to check your pyenv.cfg because it has path from the downloaded computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create virtual environment in **windows** as:
**py -m venv myenv**   (Here **myenv** is the name that users give. It can be anything you want)

Now to activate your myenv virtual environment type:**myenv\scripts\activate**

To deactivate virtual environment simply type:
**deactivate**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 7, then try `environment_path\Scripts\activate.ps1`

Also, error is saying, **The system cannot find the path specified.**, make sure your path is correct.

Remember **scripts** folder is in your virtualenv folder.