# activate virtualenv command not recognized

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to activate a virtual environment using pip virtualenv package. However, when type the following line on cmd (windows 10) it says that activate command is not recognized. virtualenv package is already installed, but for some reason I can only use it when I open the cmd as an administrator.

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\servidor\venv\Scripts>activate
"activate" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\servidor\venv\Scripts>

I appreciate any help with this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate virtual environment in Django for Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090676/how-to-activate-virtual-environment-in-django-for-windows-with-python)

Comment: I will check this out. Thank you!

Comment: In short, execute directly the _batch_ file `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`. No dot `.` or `source`, this is not for Windows.

Comment: Thank you. actually "activate" command without .bat extension worked! The problem was because of some problem with Python installation in my PC, apparently because I downloaded from Windows Store. I just uninstalled and reinstalled again Python in its latest version and followed all the instructions. Now i have the virtual environment venv working and activated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It was solved just by uninstalling and reinstalling Python in its latest version. Then I installed pip and its virtualenv package as well:

```
C:\Users\dequi>pip freeze
virtualenv==16.7.9

C:\Users\dequi>cd Desktop

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop>cd Servidor

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\Servidor>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\dequi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\Servidor\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\Servidor>cd venv

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\Servidor\venv>cd Scripts

C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\Servidor\venv\Scripts>activate

(venv) C:\Users\dequi\Desktop\Servidor\venv\Scripts>
```

The activate command worked at the end.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried: `source /path/to/my/venv/bin/activate` ?

Comment: that's the command that is being presented in the course that i'm doing:

source venv/bin/activate

But it seems that source command is not available on Windows